# Report Code (.frf file)

Tags: delphi

in the below code I would like to change the final IF NOT statement to say either HEADING or SPACE. I have tried to play around with it (I did not write this code) without success. Sorry am not an expert not sure what code it is in! Any ideas? Thanks

```
           if [POS('HEADING',[DF.Items."CODE"])] then MemoLRV.visible:=false;
       if [POS('SPACE',[DF.Items."CODE"])] then MemoLRV.visible:=false;
       if [POS('HEADING',[DF.Items."CODE"])] then MemonameV.font.Color:=clmaroon;
       if not [POS('HEADING',[DF.Items."CODE"])] then MemonameV.font.Color:=clblack;

       if not [POS('HEADING',[DF.Items."CODE"])] then MemoLRV.visible:=true;
```

Comment: judging by file extension - you use Free Reports: early opensource version of FastReports - Try using their GUI report designer or use their community http://pastebin.com/9RAy2bAH

Comment: You should be able to just add another line after that with: if not [POS('SPACE',[DF.Items."CODE"])] then MemoLRV.visible:=true;

Answer (score -1):

In FastReport function `IF` :

`IF(Expression, Value1, Value2)`

Returns `Value1` if expression `Expression` is True, otherwise returns `Value2`. Return value can be not only string.